# plsql- Inserting data into a table form 2 tables using dynamic table name is giving error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have to create a sql to insert data into table Temp198 from 2 tables (names being TRO_W.desc_tab and TRO_W.DET_TAB). Since the  part is provided during runtime based on a table, So i wrote the below query:

```
DECLARE
WSTS      VARCHAR2(2)    := 'PP';
WDET  VARCHAR2(100)   := '';
WDESC VARCHAR2(100)   := '';
CTR      NUMBER(6)      := 0;
L_SQL        VARCHAR2(5000) := '';
BEGIN
  FOR t in (SELECT DISTINCT(E_Id) FROM EnTab ORDER BY E_Id ASC)
  LOOP
    CTR := CTR + 1;
    WDESC := 'TRO_W' || t.e_id || '.desc_tab';
    WDET := 'TRO_W' || t.e_id || '.det_tab;
    L_SQL :=  'INSERT INTO Temp198 (STS, T_ID,TENT1, TENT2, VIADATE, VIDDATE, FRMEV) ' ||
          'SELECT :p1, ,B.T_ID, TENT1, A.TENT2, A.VIADATE, A.VIDDATE, :p2 from ' ||
           WDESC B, WDET A || ' WHERE A.T_ID = B.T_ID';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE L_SQL USING WSTS, CTR;
   END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS then
     raise_application_error(-20000, 'Command failed: ' || l_sql, true);
END;
/
COMMIT;
```

But this is giving error:
    Encountered the symbol "B" when expecting one of the following:
    ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
       <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
      like4 likec between || member submultiset
     06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
    *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
    *Action:

can someone check whats wrong in my query and suggest?

Comment: Is `PP` supposed to be a column name, or a fixed string value that the STS column is set to for all the rows you're inserting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got your table aliases A and B in the wrong place; they need to be parts of the string literals that form the command:

```
L_SQL :=  'INSERT INTO Temp198 (STS, T_ID,TENT1, TENT2, VIADATE, VIDDATE, FRMEV) ' ||
      'SELECT :p1, ,B.T_ID, TENT1, A.TENT2, A.VIADATE, A.VIDDATE, :p2 from ' ||
       WDESC || ' B, ' || WDET || ' A WHERE A.T_ID = B.T_ID';
```

Or using modern join syntax:

```
L_SQL :=  'INSERT INTO Temp198 (STS, T_ID,TENT1, TENT2, VIADATE, VIDDATE, FRMEV) ' ||
      'SELECT :p1, ,B.T_ID, TENT1, A.TENT2, A.VIADATE, A.VIDDATE, :p2 from ' ||
       WDESC || ' B JOIN ' || WDET || ' A ON A.T_ID = B.T_ID';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use parameters to provide columns to select. You'll need to do something like this:

```
L_SQL :=  'INSERT INTO Temp198 (STS, T_ID,TENT1, TENT2, VIADATE, VIDDATE, FRMEV) ' ||
          'SELECT PP ,B.T_ID, TENT1, A.TENT2, A.VIADATE, A.VIDDATE, '||CTR||' from ' ||
           WDESC B||','||WDET A || ' WHERE A.T_ID = B.T_ID';
```